# Tastypie ajax POST obj_create - How to return json

Tags: django, tastypie

Im sending a POST that creates a new User, and that works.

My question is how do I get back for example the pk of the created user to the ajax response?

```
         $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/create/user/',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: '{"uuid": "12345"}',
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
                success: function (r) {
                    console.log(r)
                },
            });

def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(bundle.data['uuid'],'1')
            user.save()


        except:
            pass
        return bundle
```

Answer (score 8):

you can set `always_return_data=True` within your UserResource's `Meta` and on POST and PUT request it will return the created object back.

**From the [docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#always-return-data)**

> ### always_return_data
>
> Specifies all HTTP methods (except DELETE) should return a serialized form of the data. Default is False.
>
> If False, HttpNoContent (204) is returned on POST/PUT with an empty body & a Location header of where to request the full resource.
>
> If True, HttpAccepted (202) is returned on POST/PUT with a body containing all the data in a serialized form.

Answer (score 1):

Each resource has dehydrate method. You can use it to add any data to response. Here are the docs - http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#adding-custom-values

Answer (score 1):

You could either use the Location header (set by Tastypie by default) or you could try to make Tastypie send the newly created entity back. I believe the first one is simpler. You may also take a look at related SO question: [Is it ok by REST to return content after POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829875/is-it-ok-by-rest-to-return-content-after-post)

First you need to slightly modify jQuery XHR objects,

```
// Required for reading Location header of POST responses.
var _super = $.ajaxSettings.xhr;
$.ajaxSetup({
    xhr: function () {
        var xhr = _super();
        var getAllResponseHeaders = xhr.getAllResponseHeaders;
        xhr.getAllResponseHeaders = function () {
            var allHeaders = getAllResponseHeaders.call(xhr);
            if (allHeaders) {
                return allHeaders;
            }
            allHeaders = "";
            $(["Cache-Control", "Content-Language", "Content-Type", "Expires", "Last-Modified", "Pragma", "Location"]).each(function (i, header_name) {
                if (xhr.getResponseHeader(header_name)) {
                    allHeaders += header_name + ": " + xhr.getResponseHeader(header_name) + "\n";
                }
            });
            return allHeaders;
        };
        return xhr;
    }
});
```

This is required because ([after jQuery $.ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)):

> At present, due to a bug in Firefox where .getAllResponseHeaders() returns the empty string although .getResponseHeader('Content-Type') returns a non-empty string, automatically decoding JSON CORS responses in Firefox with jQuery is not supported.
>
> A workaround to this is possible by overriding jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr as follows:

Then you can read the header in the successCallback, like so:

```
successCallback: errorAwareCall(function (data, t, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    var loc = XMLHttpRequest.getAllResponseHeaders();
    var pk = parseInt(loc.match(/\/(\d+)(\/)*/)[1]);
    // Do something with the PK
})
```