# Can method POST return response without redirecting on GET

Tags: node.js, http

I am writing node js application without using templates, because it will be mobile application or something else. While writing post method I check with test status code, and try to check response. I do: `res.send("success");`. Node unit told: `AssertionError: "success" == "`.
And I come up with fundamental question: **can method POST return response without redirecting on GET method or I did something wrong with node js?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically it can but check out the discussion here [Is it ok by REST to return content after POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829875/is-it-ok-by-rest-to-return-content-after-post/1857069#1857069) it's specifically talking about REST principles but I think it may help you here.

It's also worth mentioning that you may end up with unintended browser behaviour if you return  an html page after a post - if the user refreshes the page they will get a browser warning about reposting content. So, if you are returning an html page, don't send content in the response, redirect to a get. If you are writing an api then you can return the posted entity but it may be more expected by calling clients that the location of the posted resource is returned.

Comment: I fixed error, I just wrote word wrong, but it is the thing I want to find. Thank you.

Comment: So you mean that it is good design to provide path to url where I can find item previously added with post?

Comment: more that the better design is to redirect to a get, this will tell the browser that new entity is at the get location and it will redirect there. But, you can just return the created id or what ever if thats what the client expects and leave it to the client to redirect or not