# I'm trying to send a JSON object from client to server and receive a response but all the approaches I find are either inadequate or overkill

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, websocket, api-design

I'm in a situation where I'm not sure what is the correct way of doing this. I'm trying to take a large json file, send it to the server, process and reorder it, and then send it back to the client. I don't want to store any data in a database. I know there's the HTTP GET verb, but the amount of data I would be inputting would be longer than the max length URI. I also read that you shouldn't try to do this with a HTTP POST either.

I looked into WebSockets as well but to me it appears to be overkill. I would only need the socket for the time that it takes to do the computations, then I would close it. Also I want to share the data with only the client who sent it to me.

Does any one have recommendations as for what to do. Maybe just a push in the right direction with a few links I can read. I'm really looking for something that runs down the middle of these two methods.

Comment: This seems like a use case for POST.

Comment: That was what I was originally thinking, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829875/is-it-ok-by-rest-to-return-content-after-post) seems to discourage using it in the manner I wanted to, seems to want me to redirect to another page its hosted on. I don't want to store the data at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use a HTTP POST request? Taken from an info box on
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST

```
> Request has body                  Yes  
> Successful response has body      Yes  
> Safe                              No  
> Idempotent                        No  
> Cacheable                         Only if freshness information is included  
> Allowed in HTML forms             Yes
```

As you see, a HTTP POST request is used for sending data to the server, and if the POST request was successful, the server sends data back to the client. Perfect for your situation, I think.

A POST request doesn't have to be used within a HTML form; you could use XHR, AJAX, the fetch API, or any other way you can find to send the server a POST request. And yes, you could send JSON data with it.

If you need more convincing:

> When the POST request is sent via a method other than an HTML form — like via an XMLHttpRequest — the body can take any type. As described in the HTTP 1.1 specification, POST is designed to allow a uniform method to cover the following functions:
>
> - Annotation of existing resources
> - Posting a message to a bulletin board, newsgroup, mailing list, or similar group of articles;
> - Adding a new user through a signup modal;
> - Providing a block of data, such as the result of submitting a form, to a data-handling process;
> - Extending a database through an append operation.

Notice that there, it said that a POST request can be used to provide a block of data to a data-handling process.

Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: Thanks, I thought it might not be the best way to do it at first, but I suppose if it fits it ships.